How do I find what process is creating Time Wait TCP connections?
Ive just ran MS Sysinternals TCPView and found around 150 TCP connections in Time Wait state without indication of which process initialised it. How do I investigate?
This is on my work machine. My home Windows 11 shows around 20 of those..


can you get a PID from  netstat -ano | findstr LISTEN | findstr 52698 ? the PID should be the last column of the output. from there you can find the process executable with tasklist /SVC | findstr <PID>.

no there are no process IDs in netstat either.. i tried but didnt want to clatter the question

There's no process ID because TIME_WAIT represents an already closed connection – it effectively just reserves the port numbers (to ensure the final packets have been delivered to both sides).
Because all of these connections were made to the same destination (127.0.0.1:52698), you should watch TCPView for new connections made to this destination, which will show you the client process.
Instead of staring at TCPView you can also use SysInternals Process Monitor to get a live log of all new/closed connections.
You can also try to look up the other endpoint – 127.0.0.1:52698, which is a local listener on your system, and should have a corresponding Listening socket with the same address in the "Local" field. Once you know what process is listening for connections on that port, you can try to deduce what kind of clients it might have.

brilliant! found it was a stuck postgress admin app
